# Set up proxy server for create react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, create-react-app

I have started a react application using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and ran the `npm run eject` script to gain access to all files. I afterwards installed express and created `server.js` file that sits on same level as `package.json` file

these are `server.js` file contents:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express;

app.set('port', 3031);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('build'));
}

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Server started at: http://localhost:${app.get('port')}/`);
})
```

Nothing crazy here, just setting up for future api proxies where I need to use secrets and as I don't want to expose my api.

after this I added a `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"` to my `package.json` file. I am now stuck as I need to figure out how to start my server correctly and use this `server.js` file in development mode and afterwards in production.

Ideally It would also be good if we could use more that one proxy i.e. `/api` and `/api2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't have to eject to run your server.js. You can just run it with `node server.js` together with `create-react-app`.

You can still do `npm start` even after ejecting to start your dev server.

To run `/api1` and `/api2`, you just have to handle it in your `server.js` file and it should work just fine. You need to match the `port` in your `server.js` and the one in `proxy` settings inside `package.json` - in this case, it should be `"proxy": "http://localhost:3031"`

Comment: how can i determine the requesting client's ip address with a proxy like this?  using express, req.ip just gives me the localhost ip

Comment: @jpdelatorre Your answer is awesome and life saving one. Do you know how to setup this same option without using `create-react-app`, I mean from scratch

Comment: It still does not work for me with this solution. When I run npm run start, it still uses the localhost:3000 that the react app is running on. I know the PR is kind of big, but I have edited the package.json to match it so as you have described under react-uI/package.json https://github.com/moon-room/log/pull/1

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong still?

Comment: How to change the proxy value once the final scripts are built from react app? is it configurable?

Comment: Make sure to have the correct routes in your api server. I forgot a '/' in front of 'api/auth'. Otherwise, changing your 'package.json' should be enough.

Comment: To run server and client at the same time in one window, I recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Comment: how can I give only relative path for proxy? Means is there a way to avoid localhost?